# Calling prevent default in this scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to prevent a form from being submitted once the submit button is clicked. It should capture all the data, but not send.

I've struggled with this a bit in an attempt to get it working, but to no avail. I've tried all the below methods, but nothing.

```
function saveDetails(form){
    this.preventDefault();
}

function saveDetails(form){
    $(form).preventDefault();
}

function saveDetails(form){
    form.preventDefault();
}
```

I can capture the data easily by running `$(form).serialize();` which works perfectly. But the above does not work for stopping the submit action. Any assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call it on `event.preventDefault()`. `preventDefault` is the method of the DOM event-object. For example, you need to attach a handler to the `submit` event, that handler must do all what you need but inside itt you have to call this method

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    saveDetails();
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: ah... that explains it. I normally used it with other things and had to call e.preventDefault(), usually when I use it as callback ($('#button).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault() }); ) and I assume that's how I got confused. Thanks for the assistance! :)

Comment: Do you mean that `e.preventDefault()` did not work? If I understood you right, I have to say that there is no difference of how you define a name to the event-object which is the only argument to event handler. If call it `e`, then you have to use `e.preventDefault()`, if you called it `foo`, then `foo.preventDefault`. It is defined at the time of handler declaration e.g. `function(bar) {bar.preventDefault()}`

Comment: I posted the comment before you edited it. Using event.preventDefault() however does not work with FF

Comment: @DarkRanger , I did not understand nothing. Does it work or not?

Answer (score 1):

In the function that is executed when the form is submitted, you need to pass in the `event` object, which jQuery passes into all event callbacks, and then call `preventDefault()` on that, eg:

```
function saveDetails(form, evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var data = $(form).serialize();
  // etc
}

$("form").on("submit", function(evt) {
  saveDetails(this, evt);
});
```

Or simplify it a little:

```
function saveDetails(form) {
  var data = $(form).serialize();
  // etc
}

$("form").on("submit", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  saveDetails(this);
});
```

Comment: Just note that `$('form')` has no method `'on'`. So it has to be `$('form').submit(eventHandler);`.

Comment: @DarkRanger, yes it does. `on()` is the new (in 1.7) and preferred event binding syntax. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EJuCR/

Comment: oh snap. I see my jQuery library is a bit outdated. Will update it while I'm at updating the scripts on this page. Thanks.